# JPanel flickering with mouseMoved method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, mouse-listeners

I have a simple `JPanel` that I'm using to display an image. I want some functionality where I'm able to pan the image by dragging it. I have something like this (note the code I have compiles and runs properly; the code below is heavily truncated to just get an idea of what I'm doing):

```
public class Data2DPanel extends JPanel { 
    public Data2DPanel(Data2D data) {
        // Set image
        this.image = Data2D.data2DToBufferedImage(data);

        // Set mouse listener
        Data2DMouseAdapter data2DMouseAdapter = new Data2DMouseAdapter();
        this.addMouseListener(data2DMouseAdapter);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(data2DMouseAdapter);
    }

    private class Data2DMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                switch (actionState) {
                    case PAN:
                        xOffset = xOffsetInit + e.getX()-xPosInit;
                        yOffset = yOffsetInit + e.getY()-yPosInit;
                        paintComponent(getGraphics());
                        break;                                
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);

        // Paint image
        g2.drawImage(image,x,y,width,height,this);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there is a lot of flickering. I've checked stackoverflow/google and it seems a lot of the flickering problems are because people override the `paint` method instead of the `paintComponent` method. I've also checked `isDoubleBuffered` and it returns `true`. Intuitively, I feel maybe the `mouseDragged` method is updating too much for `paintComponent()` to keep up, but I figured double buffering should still prevent flickering from occuring. My question is if there's something inherently wrong with this approach and if there's a standard or elegant solution to this.

Comment: `paintComponent(getGraphics());` <- Do you mean `repaint()`?

Comment: @peeskillet Your suggestion worked! You can post it as an answer. I'm looking it up right now, but could you also provide a brief explanation as to why `repaint()` should be called instead of calling `paintComponent()` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paintComponent(getGraphics());` should be `repaint()`. Compounded problems.

1. You never want to make a call to `getGraphics()` for custom painting. The only `Graphics` object used to paint should be the one provided in the paint method.
2. You should never call `paintXxx` to try and *"force"* a repaint of the component. You should call `repaint()` and allow the [`RepaintManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/RepaintManager.html) to handle all the update and paint cycle